# IPMI - which sensors are available?

Tags: ipmi

Is there a way to find out which specific data / sensor types are supported via IPMI on a machine? I get the big list via `ipmi-tool -L` but many don't return a value for a new machine we just installed.

Comment: What type of server is this?

Comment: supermicro.. not sure about ipmi board version though.

Comment: are you looking for a list of sensor types supported in your server IPMI? "sensor list" is a common command supported as i knew.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one can get a reasonable list of available sensors (along with "state", "reading", "units", and "event") by using the **--entity-sensor-names** param.

```
ipmi-sensors -h <ip> -u <user> -P -l user -D LAN_2_0 --quiet-cache --sdr-cache-recreate -interpret-oem-data --output-sensor-state --entity-sensor-names
```

The 'type' column seems to (roughly) correspond to values available using the **-L** param.